# printing symbols onto an image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure, matlab-cvst

I want to ask that how can i add symbols like 'x' or 'o' onto an image permanently?

I know how to write it in a function

```
figure; imshow(I)
hold on
plot(CentroidTermX,CentroidTermY,'ro','linewidth',2)
plot(CentroidBifX,CentroidBifY,'go','linewidth',2)
```

but i want to use the resultant image in another file and also in displaying it in a gui but when i use the I as an output argument

```
function I = detection(X,Y)
```

it gives the original image without the 'ro' and 'go'. What could be the way to do it?

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: No i image is read from disk not captured from camera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are functions for that in the Computer Vision System Toolbox:

- [insertMarker](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/insertmarker.html)
- [insertShape](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/insertshape.html)
- [insertText](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/inserttext.html)
- [insertObjectAnnotation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/insertobjectannotation.html)

Comment: Yes. These functions return a new image with the markers drawn into it.

Answer (score 1):

One solution if you don't have the Computer Vision toolbox, use [`getframe`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getframe.html):

```
figure; imshow(I)
hold on
plot(CentroidTermX,CentroidTermY,'ro','linewidth',2)
plot(CentroidBifX,CentroidBifY,'go','linewidth',2)
f=getframe;
```

Then access the saved image with:

```
imshow(f.cdata);
```

Answer (score 0):

For a quick solution (without requiring too many toolboxes) I'd recommend this function: [ScreenCapture](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24323-screencapture-get-a-screen-capture-of-a-figure-frame-or-component)

Also see this useful answer:
[MATLAB: Print contents of uipanel to PNG image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15768545/matlab-print-contents-of-uipanel-to-png-image?rq=1)